# AWS IoT - Shadow update for a thing group

Tags: aws-iot

The AWS IoT developer guide explains that a Device Shadow can be updated by publishing to  the `$aws/things/thing-name/shadow/update` topic. How do I perform a Shadow update for a thing group (such that all things inside the group are updated with the same desired state)? I haven't found any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not a built-in feature, so you'll have to do this manually (e.g. there is no `$aws/thing-groups/group-name/shadow/update`).

You can use `iot::ListThingsInThingGroup` ([javascript documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Iot.html#listThingsInThingGroup-property), but it will be in all there other SDKs) to programatically list all the Things belonging to a ThingGroup. At which point you can then send a message to each thing shadow on their specific topic (or you can use [`iotData::UpdateThingShadow`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/IotData.html#updateThingShadow-property))

Alternatively, there is nothing inherently special about the shadow topic, except that the AWS device SDKs are already configured to listen to it for updates. You are free to create a `my/thing-groups/group-name/shadow/update` topic and have you devices listen to the topic for the groups they belong to. You can then manually accept the update and report back using the normal `$aws/things/thing-name/shadow/accepted` etc. topics.